# Sencha Touch store association doesn't match?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I've got two models (Category-->Object) with associations

```
Category
    |--Has many--->Objects
```

Here is the **CategoryModel**:

```
Ext.define("TouchApp.model.CategoryModel", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'id',
                type: 'int'
            },
            {
                name: 'name',
                type: 'String'
            }
        ],
        //Aide: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.Association
        associations: [
            { type: 'hasMany', model: 'ObjectsModel', primaryKey: 'id', foreignKey: 'category'}
        ]

    }
});
```

And here is the **ObjectsModel**:

```
Ext.define("TouchApp.model.ObjectsModel", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'id',
                type: 'int'
            },
            {
                name: 'name',
                type: 'String'
            },
            {
                name: 'category',
                type: 'int'
            }
        ],
        //Aide: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.Association
        associations: [
            { type: 'belongsTo', model: 'CategoryModel', primaryKey: 'id', foreignKey: 'category'}
        ]
    }
});
```

Is this association right? Otherwise, maybe I don't need to set it in the both sides?
I've got a **warning**: `[WARN][Ext.data.Operation#process] Unable to match the updated record that came back from the server.`

*PS:* I need those model to put the stores associated with in a single Nested List.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution looking [at this exemple!](http://appointsolutions.com/2012/07/using-model-associations-in-sencha-touch-2-and-ext-js-4/)

It's a really great example using every case of associations.

I finally understood the concept.

We need to set an idProperty in our Model and use hasMany and belongsTo associations.

**CategoryModel:**

```
Ext.define("TouchApp.model.CategoryModel", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
        idProperty: 'id', //The idProperty representing the "PK"
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'id',
                type: 'int'
            },
            {
                name: 'name',
                type: 'String'
            }
        ],
        //Really great example: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.Association
        hasMany: [{ model: 'TouchApp.model.ObjectsModel' }] //The hasMany association setting the model associated...
    }
});
```

**ObjectsModel:**

```
Ext.define("TouchApp.model.ObjectsModel", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
        idProperty: 'id', //The idProperty representing the "PK"
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'id',
                type: 'int'
            },
            {
                name: 'name',
                type: 'String'
            },
            {
                name: 'category',
                type: 'int'
            }
        ],
        //Realy great example: http://appointsolutions.com/2012/07/using-model-associations-in-sencha-touch-2-and-ext-js-4/
        belongsTo: [{ model: 'TouchApp.model.CategoryModel', associationKey: 'category' }] //Here the belongsTo association which tell the parent Model. AssociationKey set which key is the "FK". It will be linked to the idProperty
    }
});
```

That's it. But it doesn't work for now with my nested list...